# ActionBar gets white filled when SearchView clicked

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, searchview

I've added **SearchView** to my **ActionBar**. It normally functions correctly but when I click on it, it behaves strangely.

This is my normal state:

[image: Normal]

When I click the search icon, the ActionBar gets filled with White color:

[image: White]

The only way to get it back to normal is by tapping somewhere else and losing the focus:

[image: Unfocused]

This only happens when I put `collapseActionView` into the `android:showAsAction param`, like this:

```
android:showAsAction="collapseActionView|always".
```

If I remove the `collapseActionView` from it, then it works fine. But then the problem is that the **searchView** doesn't collapse.

How can I fix the problem?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: what is your requirement? searchview should not expand at all ??

Comment: Ty for asking @Akhil , no my problem its that the whole action bar is getting a white background (2nd image) and it shouldn't happen